# ipython macro interfering with variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

In `ipython`, I have defined a macro called `c` (this macro clears the screen).

I have noticed, when I type

```
c = 2 + 2
```

my macro `c` gets executed. I would have expected, that I am not calling a macro, but rather assigning a variable c.

Is there any way to distinguish between the two (macro vs. variable assignment)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
globals()['c'] = 2 + 2
```

will reassign the value of `c` (thus disassociating it from the definition of the macro).

I think your best option is to rename either the macro or the variable.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see any easy way to override or distinguish  a macro from a variable but `macros` **can** start with characters that are not legal in `python` variable names:

You could use `1c, $c` or any other variation that did not have the potential to clash with a python variable name.